# openXmlSdk insert new line inside of a Run Element

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I have text inside of the `Run` Element. I'm trying to replace the `\r` in the string with a `line break`.

The text as follows

```
This is an example project for testing purposes. \rThis is all sample data, none of this is real information. \r\rThis field allows for the entry of more information, a larger text field for example purposes
```

and the `innerXml` of the `Run` Element is translated into

```
<w:rPr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
   <w:rFonts w:cstheme="minorHAnsi" />
      </w:rPr>
        <w:t xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
           This is an example project for testing purposes.  This is all sample data, none of this is real information.&lt;w:br /&gt;&lt;w:br /&gt;This field allows for the entry of more information, a larger text field for example purposes.</w:t>
```

Line breaks aren't being inserted when the document is generated.

How can I replace every '\r' inside of the `<w:t> </w:t>` with a line break?

I've tried.

```
s.InnerXml = s.InnerXml.Replace("&lt;w:br /&gt;", "<w:br />");
```

I've also tried replacing it directly in the string but that doesn't work either.

it just comes out as a string

```
This is an example project for testing purposes.  This is all sample data, none of this is real information.<w:br xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" /><w:br xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" />This field allows for the entry of more information, a larger text field for example purposes.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.text.aspx#Anchor_2) states that a `Text` element contains literal text. The SDK will not make assumptions about new line characters in a string that you write to a `Text` element. How would it know if you wanted a break or if you wanted a paragraph?

If you are building the document from literal strings you will have some work to do:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

namespace OXmlTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument
                .Create("c:\\deleteme\\testdoc.docx", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

                mainPart.Document = new Document();
                Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
                Paragraph p = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());                
                Run r = p.AppendChild(new Run());

                string theString = "This is an example project for testing purposes. \rThis is all sample data, none of this is real information. \r\rThis field allows for the entry of more information, a larger text field for example purposes";

                foreach (string s in theString.Split(new char[] { '\r' }))
                {
                    r.AppendChild(new Text(s));
                    r.AppendChild(new Break());
                }

                wordDocument.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Final Document]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>This is an example project for testing purposes. </w:t>
                <w:br />
                <w:t>This is all sample data, none of this is real information. </w:t>
                <w:br />
                <w:t/>
                <w:br />
                <w:t>This field allows for the entry of more information, a larger text field for example purposes</w:t>
                <w:br />
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```