# How preserve string formatting in openxml?

Tags: c#, parsing, ms-word, openxml, office-interop

I have a string that contains multiple tabs and line breaks

```
String txt = "Some formatted string! \r\n\tLook there should be a new line 
here!\r\n\r\n\tAndthere should be 2 new lines here!"
m_wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(
        new Paragraph(
            new Run(
                new Text(txt))));
```

Once I append this text to my document the new lines and tabs are stripped off. How can I retain the new lines and tabs programatically?

What I want is for a function to handle both items, tabs and linebreaks. All examples out there are for one of the other. I'm trying to do both in one.

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us?

Comment: added the code that I have. Text is added to my document but it loses the lines breaks and tabs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [openXmlSdk insert new line inside of a Run Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566826/openxmlsdk-insert-new-line-inside-of-a-run-element)

Comment: thanks, no way to unify the two right? Ideally I would like to pass a string to a function and then the function would add the breaks and tabs.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `Break` instance to the `Run` in order to insert line breaks:

```
run.AppendChild(new Text("Some formatted string!"));
run.AppendChild(new Break());
run.AppendChild(new Text("Look there should be a new line here!"));
```

Similarly, you can add tabs by adding a `TabChar` instance to the `Run`.

In general, you can use the [Microsoft OpenXML Productivity tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) to see how these things work. Create a document in Word, open it in the tool, then use the *Reflect Code* option to see C# code.