# How to break line text in XML? I had try many times but they can't effect

Tags: c#

I parse string to `<![CDATA[{0}]]>` as below

```
string a = "<![CDATA[put returns between \r\n paragraphs \n for linebreak add 2 spaces <br/> at end]]>"
```

After I read a document (.docx) by WordprocessingDocument.

```
string docText = null;
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
   {
      docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
   }

   docText = docText.Replace("needtochange", a);

 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
   {
       sw.Write(docText);
}
```

As result is "put returns between paragraphs for linebreak add 2 spaces at end" at the same line. It does not effect.

Comment: Not sure I exactly understand, but I think you are saying that your `\r` `\n` is not creating line breaks in a Word document. That is right, it doesn't. [See if this helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566826/openxmlsdk-insert-new-line-inside-of-a-run-element/51570989#51570989)

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871887/inserting-newlines-in-word-using-openxml